# Can particles be used with (이)라고 하다?

Tags: grammar

(이)라고 하다 is used after a noun to make an indirect quotation. For example,

> 저는 외국인이라고 했어요. I said that I am a foreigner.

**Can particles (like 도, 부터,...) be used right before (이)라고 하다?**

For example, are the following sentences correct?

1. 저는 외국인도라고 했어요. I said I am also a foreigner.
2. 8시부터라고 했어요. They said it is from 8:00.

I guess topic, subject and object particles cannot be used (or at least are rarely used) from the examples I read. But how about others?

Answer (score 1):

I said that I am a foreinger. 나는 외국인이라고 했다 or 저는 외국인이라고 했습니다.

I am also a foreigner. 나는 외국인이기도 하다 or 저는 외국인이기도 합니다.

I also said I am a foreigner. 나는 외국인이라고도 했다 or 저는 외국인이라고도 했습니다.

I said I am also a foreigner. 나는 외국인이기도 하다고 했다 or 저는 외국인이기도 하다고 했습니다.

They said it is from 8:00. (그들이/ 그 사람들이) 8시부터라고 했다/했어요. (So you are correct)

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that the verbs in my examples were wrong. Is there a rule or a list of particles (like 부터)  for which 라고 can be added?

Comment: I think it is almost always possible.

Comment: Could you add a list of the exceptions (도,이/가,을/를,...) you know? I think this would make the answer more complete.

Comment: I don't know any exception. I said "almost" just because I was not 100% sure. Just make sure that you choose the correct one between 이라고 and 라고. Also there might be some cases where you need quotation marks, and other cases where you are grammatically correct but don't sound very natural. For example, in most cases, "나를"이라고 했다 and 나라고 했다 can be used interchangeably, but the latter sounds much more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion arises from two different usages of "라고".  (There are other uses, but I'll just talk about these two here.)

First, it can be used for verbatim [direct quotation](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/8faf480166e84870be6f3f5cc6e51656).  Since it's verbatim, it can attach to pretty much anything.  It's also always 라고/이라고, regardless of what's inside the quote.

> 나는 "지금 몇 시냐?"**라고** 물었다.

> 철수는 "무엇을"**이라고** 적은 다음 그 밑에 다시 "what"**이라고** 적었다.

Second, it can be an [indirect quotation](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/51f13cdba0c24e788549f69620f20fa8) after a command or the copula "이다".  Other verb/adjective forms use other suffixes such as -다고/-자고/-냐고/etc.

> 경찰은 철수가 범인**이라고** 발표했다.  (direct: 경찰은 "철수가 범인입이다."라고 발표했다.)

> 나는 지금 세 시**라고** 말했다.  (direct: 나는 "지금 세 시야."라고 말했다.)

> 선생님은 숙제를 내일까지 내**라고** 말하셨다.  (direct: 선생님은 "숙제를 내일까지 내라."라고 말하셨다.)

> 지수는 날씨가 좋**다고** 말했다.  (direct: 지수는 "날씨가 좋다."라고 말했다.)

> 선희는 지금 몇 시**냐고** 물었다.  (direct: 선희는 "지금 몇 시야?"라고 물었다.)

> 동생은 집에 가**자고** 했다.  (direct: 동생은 "집에 가자."라고 했다.)

So, going back to your question, I think "저는 외국인도라고 했어요." isn't right - I think it only makes sense if it was a direct quotation, that is, you literally uttered the phrase "외국인도" and you are quoting yourself: 저는 "외국인도"라고 했어요.  (It's still a pretty unusual phrase to quote.)  In general, I don't think you can add stuff after the suffix -도.

> 너만을 사랑해 / 그것만은 안됩니다.  (OK)

> 너도를 사랑해 / 그것도는 안됩니다.  (X)

The second sentence "8시부터라고 했어요." is fine: it's indirectly quoting "8시부터다" where the final 다 is a shortened version of 이다.

---

Finally, be careful about what you mean by "also".  There are two possibilities:

> I am a cook, but I'm **also a foreigner.** => 나는 요리사인데 **외국인이기도 하다**.

> John is a foreigner, and **I am also** a foreigner. => 존은 외국인이고 **나도** 외국인이다.